# How can i export just some packages from a Spring Boot project and execute it in another non-Spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

i developed a springboot project composed by 2 parts, client and server.
Now i would like to export the package "client" only and import/execute the jar in another non-springboot project to make it interct with the server.
The interaction between client-server happens through RabbitMq queues.
Thanks to everyone that will help me.
Cheers

Comment: Put the common classes in a separate maven project and use it as dependency in both the projects.

Comment: Thanks @KarthikeyanVaithilingam for the answer. The problem is that the other program is build without maven and then i couldnt use it

Comment: No issues you can still use the jar file from the common project target folder in the class-path of the non-maven project.

Comment: I am doing it but i cannot start the springboot project